# ¿Por qué se superponen el título y los filtros?

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tengo el siguiente code:

```
<div class="card-header bg-white">
    <div id="people-filters" class="bg-white">
        <form method="POST" action="http://p.miurl.local" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="search-form">
            <input value="xxxxxx" type="hidden" name="_token" class="field-token" /> <input value="1" id="field-page" type="hidden" name="page" class="field-page" />
            <div class="d-none d-lg-block">
                <div class="row m-t-10 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-3"><h3>Title</h3></div>
                    <div class="col-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                        <span class="text-nowrap">Sort by:</span>
                        <div class="form-group w-100 m-0 pl-3">
                            <select
                                id="field-sort-by"
                                name="sort_by"
                                data-value=""
                                data-null-option="Sort By"
                                accesskey="s"
                                class="custom-select form-control field-sort-by select2-hidden-accessible"
                                tabindex="-1"
                                aria-hidden="true"
                                data-select2-id="field-sort-by"
                            >
                                <option value="" selected="selected" data-select2-id="9">Sort By</option>
                                <option value="first_name.asc">Name</option>
                                <option value="created_at.desc">Newest</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="8" style="width: 342.828px;">
                                <span class="selection">
                                    <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-field-sort-by-container">
                                        <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-field-sort-by-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="Sort By">Sort By</span>
                                        <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                                <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                        <span>Search</span>
                        <div class="form-group w-100 m-0 pl-3"><input placeholder="Search users" value="" id="field-name" accesskey="n" type="text" name="name" class="people-name-search form-control field-name" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Le he agregado `<div class="d-none d-lg-block">` para evitar que el actual code solamente se muestre en pantallas XL y LG, pero no se como hacer para que se vea bien en pantallas MD, SD y XS.

He intentado lo siguiente sin exito:

```
   <div class="d-lg-none d-xl-none">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center flex-sm-row flex-column">
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"><h3>Title</h3></div>
                <div class="col-7 col-sm-6 col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <span class="text-nowrap">Sort by:</span>
                    <div class="form-group w-100 m-0 pl-3">
                        <select name="sort_by" data-value="" data-null-option="Sort By" accesskey="s" class="custom-select form-control field-sort-by select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-select2-id="12">
                            <option value="" selected="selected" data-select2-id="14">Sort By</option>
                            <option value="first_name.asc">Name</option>
                            <option value="created_at.desc">Newest</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="13" style="width: auto;">
                            <span class="selection">
                                <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-sort_by-p3-container">
                                    <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-sort_by-p3-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="Sort By">Sort By</span>
                                    <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
                                </span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1"></div>
                <div class="col-7 col-sm-6 col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <span>Search</span>
                    <div class="form-group w-100 m-0 pl-3"><input placeholder="Search users" value="" accesskey="n" type="text" name="name" class="people-name-search form-control field-name" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que dentro del `row` estás creando un contenedor flexible, de la cual, el contenedor flexible no respetará al `row` porque el contenedor **padre** debería ser el **contenedor flexible**, y lo que estás haciendo es al revés. Lo que hice fue primero crear un contenedor flexible, y dentro de este contenedor, estaría la clase `row`. Quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
<div class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center flex-sm-row flex-column">
  <div class="row w-100">
    <!--- Todo el contenido del card --->
  </div>
</div>
```

Aquí al `row` le asigno la clase `w-100` para que el `row` ocupe todo el ancho de la pantalla.

---

También, a los bloques de adentro, les puse las siguientes clases:

```
<div class="row w-100">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12"><h3>Title</h3></div>
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center p-2">
    <!--- Tu input SortBy --->
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center p-2">
    <!--- Tu input Search --->
  </div>
</div>
```

En donde:

- `col-lg-2`, `col-lg-5`, `col-lg-5`: Los 3 bloques ocupan el ancho `12` de la pantalla (dividido en `2` / `5` / `5`).
- `col-md-12`, `col-md-12`, `col-md-12`: Y cuando el ancho de la pantalla sea [**`sm`**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options), los 3 bloques ocuparán todo el ancho `12` de la pantalla.

---

Reestructurando tu código con las observaciones dadas, quedaría así:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="p-5">
  <div class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center flex-sm-row flex-column">
    <div class="row w-100">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12"><h3>Title</h3></div>
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center p-2">
        <span class="text-nowrap">Sort by:</span>
        <div class="form-group w-100 m-0 pl-3">
          <select name="sort_by" data-value="" data-null-option="Sort By" accesskey="s" class="custom-select form-control field-sort-by select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-select2-id="12">
            <option value="" selected="selected" data-select2-id="14">Sort By</option>
            <option value="first_name.asc">Name</option>
            <option value="created_at.desc">Newest</option>
          </select>
          <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="13" style="width: auto;">
            <span class="selection">
              <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-sort_by-p3-container">
                <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
              </span>
            </span>
            <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center p-2">
        <span>Search:</span>
        <div class="form-group w-100 m-0 pl-3"><input placeholder="Search users" value="" accesskey="n" type="text" name="name" class="people-name-search form-control field-name" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Puedes ver mejor los resultados en [**éste enlace**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/GRBLewq).

Comment: el resultado no me queda de esa forma, voy a pasarte una screenshot

Comment: https://ibb.co/k6784Dz y https://ibb.co/61xj704 Esto sucede cuando ajusto el tamano del navegador, no obstante, al presionar F5 se ve bien. Como se puede actualizar esto en tiempo real (para que se adapte)?

Comment: Al presionar F5 se soluciona?... que extraño... estás agregando un código adicional? podrías compartirme tu código en https://codepen.io/ para visualizarlo mejor? Yo lo veo perfecto en todos los dispositivos... me avisas.

Comment: Correcto, al presionar F5 se soluciona, he estado horas viendo esto y no encuentro el problema.

Comment: Estoy usando Laravel para generar un par de componentes HTML, creo que el problema es la siguiente linea: {!! Form::select('sort_by', \App\Models\User\User::SORTING_ORDERS, ['class' => 'custom-select', 'null-option' => 'Sort By']) !!} (que genera el HTML que he publicado en la pregunta, especificamente el select cuyo name es 'sort_by'. Sabes si debe hacer un js para inicializar eso?